# AVX2: BitScanReverse or CountLeadingZeros on 8 bit elements in AVX register

Tags: c++, simd, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I would like to extract the index of the highest set bit in a 256 bit AVX register with 8 bit elements. I could neither find a `bsr` nor a `clz` implementation for this.

For `clz` with 32 bit elements, there is the bithack with a float conversion, but that is probably not possible for 8 bits.

Currently, I am working on a solution, where I check the bits one by one, which I will add later, but I wonder if there is a faster way to do this.

Comment: The highest bit of each 8 bit element, or the highest bit of the 256bit register?

Comment: Also, what shall be the result for `0`?

Comment: Can AVX512 be used?

Comment: @chtz highest bit of each 8 bit element.

`0` can not be the case, so whatever is fastest.

@AlexGuteniev preferably not. But if there is a solution using AVX512, I'd love to see it!

Comment: I would do a combination of two `pshufb`-based look-up-tables (for higher and lower half). I can make a possible implementation later, if nobody is faster.

Comment: You can try your scalar algorithm in opencl for cpu and check the produced vectorized kernel assembly codes. But it doesnt work for special function implementations like exp sqrt etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a `vpshufb` based solution. The idea is to split the input into two halves, make a lookup on both and combine the results:

```
__m256i clz_epu8(__m256i values)
{
    // extract upper nibble:
    __m256i hi = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srli_epi16(values, 4), _mm256_set1_epi8(0xf));
    // this sets the highest bit for values >= 0x10 and otherwise keeps the lower nibble unmodified:
    __m256i lo = _mm256_adds_epu8(values, _mm256_set1_epi8(0x70));

    // lookup tables for count-leading-zeros (replace this by _mm256_setr_epi8, if this does not get optimized away)
    // ideally, this should compile to vbroadcastf128 ...
    const __m256i lookup_hi = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_setr_epi8(0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    const __m256i lookup_lo = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_setr_epi8(8, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4));

    // look up each half
    __m256i clz_hi = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup_hi, hi);
    __m256i clz_lo = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup_lo, lo);

    // combine results (addition or xor would work as well)
    return _mm256_or_si256(clz_hi, clz_lo);
}
```

godbolt-link with crude test: https://godbolt.org/z/MYq74Wxdh

Comment: On my machine, there is no `_mm_broadcastsi128_si256`, but only `_mm256_broadcastsi128_si256`. According to the intrinsics guide, both exist, but they do the same?! Also for some reason, I get a memory error, when I would run this with `_mm256_broadcastsi128_si256`: "accessed RAM at 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", which is not the case on godbolt.

Comment: Accepted the edit. Probably it would actually be better to replace this by a `_mm256_setr_epi8` so that it at least does not generate sub-optimal code on gcc. On the other hand, if you call this in a loop the compiler should be able to move the initialization out of the loop.

Comment: So replace each line with:
`__m256i lookup_hi = _mm256_setr_epi8(0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
`
Also, if I would want the position of the leftmost bit that is `1`, I would probably have to "invert" the values, so for each `1`, I would set a `7`, for a `2` a `6`, etc., correct?

Comment: For the leftmost bit set to `1`, you want to replace the lines with:
`__m256i lookup_hi = _mm256_setr_epi8(0, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7);` and `__m256i lookup_lo = _mm256_setr_epi8(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3);`

Comment: @simonlet: looks right to me (I suggest to just test it with all possible values ...)

Comment: [aqrit's new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70467712/224132) shows using `_mm_min_epu8` instead of `adds` / `or`, with the right table constants.  That would of course work for the AVX2 version as well, since it's pure vertical or at least in-lane counting vpshufb.

Answer (score 3):

Normally `_mm_shuffle_epi8` needs masking to isolate each nibble to use it as a LUT, because having the high bit set makes that output element 0.  But for CLZ, if the high bit is set, the correct result is for the whole byte is `0`, and the way we combine means it's fine for `lut_lo` to produce it.

```
__m128i ssse3_lzcnt_epi8(__m128i v) {
    const __m128i lut_lo = _mm_set_epi8(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8);
    const __m128i lut_hi = _mm_set_epi8(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 8);
    __m128i t;

    t = _mm_and_si128(_mm_srli_epi16(v, 4), _mm_set1_epi8(0x0F));
    t = _mm_shuffle_epi8(lut_hi, t);
    v = _mm_shuffle_epi8(lut_lo, v);
    v = _mm_min_epu8(v, t);
    return v;
}
```

This saves an instruction vs. using `_mm_adds_epu8` and combining LUT results with `or`.

Answer (score 1):

AVX512 solution, didn't try it, but I think the idea should work:

```
// Form four 32-bit vectors with high bytes from the source
__m256i a0 = _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_slli_si256(a, 3),  _mm256_set1_epi32(0x00FF'FFFF));
__m256i a1 = _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_slli_si256(a, 2),  _mm256_set1_epi32(0x00FF'FFFF));
__m256i a2 = _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_slli_si256(a, 1),  _mm256_set1_epi32(0x00FF'FFFF));
__m256i a3 = _mm256_or_si256(                  a,      _mm256_set1_epi32(0x00FF'FFFF));
// Count lead bits and shift according to bit position
__m256i c0 =                   _mm256_lzcnt_epi32(a0);
__m256i c1 = _mm256_slli_si256(_mm256_lzcnt_epi32(a1), 1);
__m256i c2 = _mm256_slli_si256(_mm256_lzcnt_epi32(a2), 2);
__m256i c3 = _mm256_slli_si256(_mm256_lzcnt_epi32(a3), 3);
//Gather the result
__m256i r  = _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_or_si256(c0,c1),_mm256_or_si256(c2,c3));
```

Not sure if it is faster than checking one by one

Comment: chtz posted a vpshufb answer that could be ported to 512-bit vectors if needed.  It's very likely faster (except possibly on KNL where only 32-bit elements are efficient), especially with its clever `adds` to make merging the results efficient.

Comment: @PeterCordes, today I learned that `pshufb` does not only work as a shuffle, but also as a small LUT

Answer (score 0):

Given a target AVX register `_a`, this works. Let me know (or edit directly) if there is something to optimize.

```c
__m256i _a;
__m256i _old_mask = _mm256_set1_epi8(-1);
__m256i _extract_bitmask, _extracted_bit, _mask;

for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
{
    // bitmask to extract bit from _a at position i
    _extract_bitmask = _mm256_set1_epi8(1 << i);

    // the extracted bit
    _extracted_bit = _mm256_and_si256(_a, _extract_bitmask);
    
    // check if bit at position i is set and if was not set before
    _mask = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(_extract_bitmask, _extracted_bit);
    _mask = _mm256_and_si256(_mask, _old_mask);
    
    // update mask
    _old_mask = _mm256_andnot_si256(_mask, _old_mask);

    // update result according to _mask
    _result = _mm256_blendv_epi8(_result, _mm256_set1_epi8(i), _mask);
}
```

Comment: This whole strategy is certainly not optimal; lookup tables with vpshufb are clearly better, even if you didn't come up with as efficient a way to separate / combine high 
 and low halves as chtz's answer.  But just as a learning exercise, there are some inefficiencies in the details here: `_extract_bitmask = _mm256_set1_epi8(1 << i);` might compile really inefficiently.  Start with `bmask = set1_epi8(1)` outside the loop, and shift it left with `bmask = _mm256_add_epi8(bmask, bmask)`.  i.e. a strength-reduction optimization from variable-shift+broadcast to single-bit vector shift.

Comment: Also, for style, there's no reason to use leading underscores on your var names.  Intrinsic functions already have enough underscores.  Use `v` as a leading letter for vectors if you need to distinguish from non-vectors in the same function.  Also, only declare loop-carried variables outside the loop.  Do `__m256i mask = cmp(bmask, bit)` in the loop so it's clear that this mask value isn't used next iteration.  Also, normally you'd want to initialize a C variable before reading it, like with `result`, e.g. with `8` in case of not-found, unless you intentionally want a=0 to leave it unmodified.

Comment: Also, I think you can use `_mm256_cmpgt_epi8(_mm256_setzero_si256(), a)` to test the sign bit of each element of `a` without any ANDing, just need to left-shift `a` by 1 each iteration.