# AVX2: CountTrailingZeros on 8 bit elements in AVX register

Tags: c++, simd, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I would like to have an implementation for a function like `_mm256_lzcnt_epi8(__m256i a)`, where for every 8 bit element the number of trailing zeros is counted and extracted.

In a previous question to implement counting leading zeros there is a solution using a lookup table. I wonder if one can use the same method for this.

Only AVX and AVX2 please and behaviour for `0` as input can be undefined.

[AVX2: BitScanReverse or CountLeadingZeros on 8 bit elements in AVX register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68985039/avx2-bitscanreverse-or-countleadingzeros-on-8-bit-elements-in-avx-register)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same LUT as in [the answer by chtz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68987092/2945027) in that question should work.

Saturation trick won't work, but `_mm256_blendv_epi8` can be used to select which LUT results to use.

The low LUT is the answers for values 0..15, for 0 it is 0xFF to see in the other LUT via blendv.

Like this (not tested):

```cpp
__m256i ctz_epu8(__m256i values)
{
    // extract upper nibble:
    __m256i hi = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srli_epi16(values, 4), _mm256_set1_epi8(0xf));
    // extract lower nibble:
    __m256i lo = _mm256_and_si256(values, _mm256_set1_epi8(0xf));

                                                                   // 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 
    const __m256i lookup_hi = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_set_epi8(4, 5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 4, 7, 4, 5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 4, 8));
    
                                                                   // 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
    const __m256i lookup_lo = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_set_epi8(0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0xFF));

    // look up each half
    __m256i ctz_hi = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup_hi, hi);
    __m256i ctz_lo = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup_lo, lo);

    // combine results
    return _mm256_blendv_epi8(ctz_lo, ctz_hi, ctz_lo);
}
```

Comment: This is not working yet. Can you explain how you came up with the numbers for `lookup_hi` and `lookup_lo`, so I might fix it? And also please explain what the `ctz_hi` and `ctz_lo` should contain for some example input? Thanks!

Comment: @simonlet, apparently I forgot to change setr to set, please try again

Comment: @simonlet, the other answer is slightly better, `(v)pminsb` is more efficient way to combine results than `(v)pblendvb`. Maybe even worth changing `clz` solution to use `min_epu8` as well, to follow that pattern.

Comment: I need the function for 256 bit registers, so I will just use your function with `return _mm256_min_epu8(clz_lo, clz_hi);`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
__m128i ssse3_tzcnt_epi8(__m128i v) {
    const __m128i lut_lo = _mm_set_epi8(0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 8);
    const __m128i lut_hi = _mm_set_epi8(4, 5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 4, 7, 4, 5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 4, 8);
    const __m128i nibble_mask = _mm_set1_epi8(0x0F);
    __m128i t;

    t = _mm_and_si128(nibble_mask, v);
    v = _mm_and_si128(_mm_srli_epi16(v, 4), nibble_mask);
    t = _mm_shuffle_epi8(lut_lo, t);
    v = _mm_shuffle_epi8(lut_hi, v);
    v = _mm_min_epu8(v, t);
    return v;
}
```